# How do I set up tab stops for use with COBOL?

Tags: notepad++, cobol

I have an assignment to write some COBOL code.  I've used Notepad++ before and was able to set up tab stops at columns 7,8,12, and 72.  I can't find the location to set those tab stops up this time.  I've searched the Notepad++ user guide, but found nothing.

I did it once, but, I cannot find it now.

Help.  How do I set up the tab stops as I listed them above for a COBOL source code program.

Answer (score -1):

Notepad++ v5. 6.6

```
Click on the Settings menu.
Select Preferences.
Go to the Language Menu/Tab Settings tab.
Make sure [Default] is selected in the rightmost list.
At The bottom right, click the blue underlined number beside the Tab size:
Press 2, and press enter.
Check Replace by space.
Click Close.
```

(direct paste from https://www.google.com/search?q=notepad%2B%2B+tabstop ; click "People also ask")